# Rails 4: ActiveModelSerializer how to include only those records which are approved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

In my Rails 4.2 API, I'm using active model serializers for constructing json response. Suppose `Post` is a model and it has many `comments` and I only want to include comments which are approved/published. I'm using a scope called `approved` which gives approved comments.

JSON response for post includes all comments, how do I include records which are approved and not everything. How do I construct Post serializer for that.

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :body
  has_many :comments
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :body
  has_many :comments

  def comments
    object.comments.where( status: 'approved' )
  end
end
```

See [Active Model Serializers - overriding association methods](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#overriding-association-methods)

Comment: It says `(lambda)> is not a symbol nor a string`

Comment: @StarWars my mistake. Updated. You can, of course, `scope :approved, ...` in the Comment class and use `object.comments.approved` above

Comment: thanks. it worked. Is this the best/only way to do this?

Comment: I would say scoping from the Comment class would be a better way ( reusable and hides the implementation of the status ). I'm sure there are other ways, but 'best' really depends on trade-offs. For the sake of discussion, we can refactor to an 'ApprovedComment' class if there are sufficient reasons to do so.

Comment: As of now I'm using what you've suggested in this answer, and have a `approved` scope in the model. i.e. `object.comments.approved`.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding associations in your serializer will work. In serializer just override with this method

```
def comments   
  #Your comments filtering 
end
```

If that doesn't work then that has got to be some issue with your version of serializer. Look at this issue for more details and workarounds. https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/267

Check this out too. [How do I select which attributes I want for active model serializers relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854013/how-do-i-select-which-attributes-i-want-for-active-model-serializers-relationshi?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :name, :body
   has_many :approved_comments, -> { where status: 'approved' }, class_name: 'Comment'
 end

 PostSerializer.includes(:approved_comments)
```

Scoping with the `approved_comments`. Fetching only the comments with the status of `approved`.
Got the concept from this
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.